# using a variable in an R1C1 formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This formula works:
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-14]C:R[-1]C)"`
it returns `=sum(c1:c14)`

This formula does not work:
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & nrows & "]C:R[-1]C)"`
It returns `=SUM(C14:C1048576)`

I have this statement

```
Dim nrows as Integer
```

why does the formula with the nrows variable not work

Comment: Keep in mind that integers can only hold values up to 32767, so it would be better to Dim it as a `Long` instead.

Comment: nrows will likely be less than 100

Comment: What's the value of `nrows` when you get that result, and where is `ActiveCell` ?

Comment: You need to include the part of code that is calculating `nrows`.

Comment: Tim Williams - nrows changes could be anywhere from 1 to 100.  It is calculated by counting the rows in the spreadsheet.

Comment: ActiveCell is at the bottom of the column

Comment: Does it *always* fail no matter the value of `nrows` or the location of the activecell ?  Please include some *specific* values for when it fails.  It's working fine for me unless the activecell is above row 14 (eg when nrows is 14)

Comment: Maybe your requirement is `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R" & (nrows - 1) & "C)"`.

Comment: @aoswald If you declare as `Integer`, then Excel will allocate the Memory for a `Long` anyway, but just lock half of it as unavailable.  There is zero advantage to using `Integer` instead of `Long` in VBA (however, I believe that this does *not* apply to VB.Net)

Comment: @shrivallabha redij your suggestion worked - thanks

Comment: I have added an answer with explanation for any future users who stumble onto this question. Hth.

Answer (score 3):

Your "wrong" results are because R1C1 formulas will "wrap", so for example if your active cell is A1 and you enter `=R[-1]C` you will get `=A1048576` (last cell in ColA) as a result.

Similarly `=RC[-1]` in A1 gives you `=XFD1`

Answer (score 2):

One should be careful while implementing R1C1 style formulas unless one is recording them directly using Macro Recorder.

Style is: `<Row><Number><Column><Number>`

First part is type of reference.

**Absolute Reference:** In case of absolute references, notation does not contain square brackets and number written indicates the explicit location of cell in the grid.
e.g.

`R1C1` denotes `$A$1` i.e. Row 1 and Column 1

`R2C1` denotes `$A$2`

`R1C2` denotes `$B$1`

Usage of absolute references is fairly straightforward as one can fairly quickly understand the cell location in the grid.

**Relative Reference:** In case of relative references, notation requires usage of square brackets. See below image for clear understanding of offset notation.

[image]

So if your current cell is `B2` then formula

`=R[-1]C` will refer `B1`

`=RC[-1]` will refer `A2` and so on as shown in the image.

**Your specific case:**

You can use

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R" & (nrows - 1) & "C)"`

which basically means if your `ActiveCell` is `C16` and variable `nrows` is `16` then you will get following formula which uses absolute reference technique for rows.

`=SUM(C$1:C$15)` i.e. mixed references.

For relative references you can use:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -(nrows - 1) & "]C:R[-1]C)"` will get

`=SUM(C1:C15)` i.e. Relative References

For absolute references assuming you want in Column C it will become:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C3:R" & (nrows - 1) & "C3)"` will get

`=SUM($C$1:$C$15)` i.e. Absolute References

**Additional notes:**

- Notation `=RC` refers to ActiveCell itself.
- Relative style references are wrapped i.e. `=RC[-1]` in column A refers to the last column in the sheet and similarly `=R[-1]C` in the first row refers to the last row in the sheet.